# Possible to have a single progress bar across mutliple purrr::map() calls

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Is it possible to have a single progress bar across multiple purrr::map() calls.

For example, when doing map() within a single mutate() call, I would like to know how long it has taken overall, rather than for each individual map().

I have looked through the options for progress bars in purrr and currently I am not sure it is possible, but willing to be proved wrong.

Below is an example. I would like a single progress bar rather than multiple.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# write simple function to sleep system for x seconds

# create random function to get progress bar
random_function <- function(x){
  Sys.sleep(x/10)
  return(x)
}

# create random data frame
x <- tibble(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)

# create progress options
progress_options <- list(name = 'Progress', clear = FALSE)

# write example
x <- nest(x, data = b) %>%
  mutate(time = map(data, ~random_function(.x$b), .progress = progress_options),
         time2 = map(data, ~random_function(.x$b), .progress = progress_options))
#> Progress ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■            70% |  ETA:  1s
#> Progress ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■  100% |  ETA:  0s
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>